# Flurry Integration Error: Cannot find symbol method init()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, flurry, flurry-analytics

In my application class, in OnCreate(), I've added the following bit of code:

```
new FlurryAgent.Builder()
                .withDataSaleOptOut(false) //CCPA - the default value is false
                .withCaptureUncaughtExceptions(true)
                .withIncludeBackgroundSessionsInMetrics(true)
                .withLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE)
                .withPerformanceMetrics(FlurryPerformance.ALL)
                .build(context, API_KEY);
```

Also, in the gradle, I've added implementation like,

```
implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:12.11.0'
```

Now, when I'm trying to add FlurryAgent.init(Context, String) in a method, I'm receiving the error "cannot find symbol method init(Context, String). The same is the case with FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(True).

This is the first time I'm working with Flurry. Can anyone please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

`FlurryAgent.init(Context, String)` method was removed from Flurry SDK. You should use `FlurryAgent.Builder()...build(Context, String)` to initialize Flurry.

Looks like you already use `FlurryAgent.Builder.build` here. You don't need to use `FlurryAgent.init` again.

Comment: But I created an apk, and I saw no session record on the flurry website. Any reason for that?

Comment: Try to log some events. The sessions may not be visible until few hours later.